# "Nominate for bounty" option

Tags: feature-request, voting, bounties

## Eligible users should be able to nominate questions for a bounty.

#### How is it beneficial?

Bounty nomination for questions and answers would attract attention to questions which are actually worthwhile, or notably great answers.

#### How would spam / serial nominations be handled?

Keep reading.

#### How are these gonna be used?

There will be a link in the same bar as the `share, edit, close, flag` bar with the word `nominate`.  If a question receives, say, 5 nominations, it will appear in the Featured section.  The question will reward a small (+15) bounty to the selected answerer.

#### Who can use it? / How often can they use it?

The feature will only be available to 1k+ rep users, and you can only nominate **once per week**. The nominee must have at least 100 rep to prevent nomination of inactive user questions. You cannot nominate your own question/answer.

---

**If you disagree**, I respect your downvote but please comment why this is a bad idea, or how this could be improved.

Comment: The upvote functionality is meant to supply such information already. Being able to nominate one post/day means the result will be a function of me randomly seeing one worthy post before another one, even more worthy.

Comment: Does this not cause inflation of reputation? in other words, devaluation.

Comment: I don't understand your clarification comment. How does your proposal take rep from other users to create the bounty? Aren't you proposing that bounties be nominated for free and created out of nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **How is it beneficial?**
>
> Bounty nomination for questions and answers would attract attention to
>   questions which are actually *worthwhile, or notably great answers*.

That is just what you *want* to happen. What will actually *make* that happen?

Why would userA, userB, and userC, place a bounty on anything "worthwhile"?

Forgive my speculation, but, *surely* 60%/70% or more of users are going to put this "free" bounty on question *they want answered*, regardless of quality, worthiness, or anything else?

### Work for free/no attraction

A (current) bounty is rep someone has put up. It attracts answers because people get rep in return.

Without a *current* bounty with rep, why would anyone spend more time answering a question with *your* free bounty than they would now *without* it?
In both scenarios they get the same back - nadda - helping someone else, which they can do now.

It might make it prominent in that it's in a special area (featured tab), but this is going to be filled up so no longer prominent:

### Self-destruction

It's free, so everyman and their dog and cat are going to use their vote every day on a question they want answering.
Surely? Why wouldn't they?

(the following is just an example and not intended to be accurate, just an idea to show an issue).

4 million users on Stack Overflow.
Let's remove 50% each time for users who:

1. Are inactive/never log in
2. Would not use it
3. Not aware of it
4. Have no questions they want answering
5. Something else in case I've missed one
6. Something else because it's Thursday
7. Something else for the hell of it

I think my *gross generosity* there with the reductions is going to give us some sort of realistic scenario (not accuracy at all, but arguably a *realistic scenario*).
I've halved the total every time for each potential.

Total - 31250 users

Divide by 3 (as requires 3 votes and every user only has one per day).

So, on the first day of feature release, there are 10417 questions in the featured tab.
*Ten thousand questions* (gulp)

Sorry, but we can already see this is pointless just for this reason.

However, how long are they going to be in there? Of course there will be an equilibrium.
Let's say 5 days, 3 is pointless as not all professionals might see your nominated question in that time, and 7 perhaps too long given the issue I'm highlighting here.

By day 5, the featured tab has 52085 questions, and will remain at that amount from then on.

As there is no rep up for grabs, you have essentially just made the *featured tab* into a new basic listing tab filled with the sites questions.

:(

### Re-think

I can see *why* you had this idea, but as it stands it just won't work.

I've thought about some solutions, such as limiting the total number of Qs allowed in the featured tab, but given 30,000 users want 10,000 questions in there, there is no fair way to limit it.

I cannot see a way around such problems, but have a re-think now you have feedback.
This is the point of a community debate ;)

Comment: Tweaked part of my proposal to limit the feature to **1k+ users** and only 1 nomination **per week**.  I can see that it probably won't work, but perhaps a better system could be derived from it.

Answer (score 13):

The point of a bounty is to sacrifice your own rep on something important. Nominating for a bounty bypasses all of that, to little or no gain.

A bounty from your proposal:

- costs nothing (no sacrifice)
- dilutes the existing bounty system
- is rampant for fraud
- makes more work for mods

I say no